# iOS, How to call IBAction inside UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, uialertview, ibaction

What I want to call an IBAction when a user clicks on "YES" in `UIAlertView`, for that I have:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.tag == 12) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            // How can I post IBAction here ???
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_to_call" sender:self];
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [self yourIBActionMethod:nil];? See there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457566/how-can-i-call-an-ibaction-in-the-viewdidload

Comment: You can call IBAction method with the current class instance inside the alertview subviews.

Comment: IBAction is itself a void return type method

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi, I added `-(IBAction)sliderValue:(id)sender;` inside the code, but It does not work :s

Comment: You can not call the method using this syntax. You have to call it like `[self sliderValue:nil];`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your `IBAction` method is :

```
-(IBAction) sliderValue:(id)sender
{
   // SOME CODE
}
```

You can call the method like this

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(alertView.tag == 200){

        if (buttonIndex==1) {           
        [self sliderValue:nil]; //Here is your IBAction Method          
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_to_call" sender:self];
       }
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems to be working, but the problem, that I does NOT respect the `if condition` meaning, that It executes the IBAction before hitting `YES` on the UIAlertView. Any ideas on what's causing this issue ?

Comment: Can you elaborate you problem?

Comment: It is right, because it hides the error, and it is wrong because it does NOT do any effect :s

Comment: It will perform the action you have wrote inside the `-(IBAction) sliderValue:(id)sender`

Comment: Well, it does not perform it. This is the issue :s

Comment: You are not able to see it working because you are calling the next view using `segue`. Comment the line `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_to_call" sender:self]; ` and you can see evrything all right. :)

Comment: Still, the same problem. It performs the IBAction before showing the UIAlertView !

Comment: Inside IBAction I wrote `NSLog(@"This is text");` it shows in terminal `This is text` before clicking on yes in the UIAlertView !

Comment: Edited the code.. please check... And what is the position of `YES` button in `AlertView`?

Comment: This is inside the IBAction :

 `UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure want to post ?" message:nil delegate:self
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                         otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];
        alertView.tag=200;
        [alertView show];`

Comment: yes, but the concept is wrong, there is something there that does not let it to do action.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 -(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
       if (alertView.tag == 12) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            [self methodName:nil];
        }
    }
}

-IBAction) methodName {
    NSLog(@"Method run in this");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please make it more clear, by showing the IBAction instead of `[self methodname:parameter]` ??

Comment: I want to insert IBAction, not a void function. Please make it clear.

Comment: use simply [self methodName :nil]; -(IBAction)methodName
{

}